# Postgresql 9.6: select data from table as JSON where table.id as JSON key

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have simple table:

```
id | info
---------
1  | {"i":123}
2  | {"i":456}
---------
```

Which way I can select all data like this JSON?

```
{
  "1":{"i":123},
  "2":{"i":456}
}
```

Comment: `select json_object_agg(id,info) from table;`

Comment: Good idea! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select format('{%s}',string_agg(format('"%s": %s', id, info), ','))::jsonb
from t
;
               format               
------------------------------------
 {"1": {"i": 123}, "2": {"i": 456}}
```